# How to select a tab without triggering listener?

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have multiple tabs and let's say:

1. The user swipes down: it should change tabs depending on which
   category it is on.
2. The user clicks on the tab: it should move
   to the the top of the view the category is on.

My problem is when I select the tab once the user gets to a certain view, it triggers `onTabSelected` and slides to the top of the view.

Is there a way I could change the tab selected without triggering the Listener?

This is my code

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public RecyclerView firstView,secondView;
    public NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meat_category);

//removed unimportant codes


        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

          tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() { // I removed the boolean here because I don't know where to change the value of it.
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0){
                    nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, firstView.getTop());
                }else if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 1){
                    nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, secondView.getTop());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if (scrollY <= firstView.getBottom()){
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
                    clicked = false;
                } else if (scrollY >= secondView.getTop() && scrollY <= secondView.getBottom() ){
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
                    clicked = false;
                }

            }

        });




    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code for more information.

Comment: You could temporarily remove the `OnTabSelectedListener` – i.e., call `setOnTabSelectedListener(null)` – and then set it back afterwards. Alternatively, you could keep some sort of flag variable – e.g., a `boolean` – to indicate whether or not you should anything in `onTabSelected()`.

Comment: hey mike thanks for the suggestion. I had already tried the boolean. I had trouble wrapping my head on how to change the value if the user clicked the tabs instead of scrolling. Ive edit my question.

Comment: @SavinSharma I've updated it!

Comment: @Kristofer Why you are scrolling your nested view to the top every time you change the tab? This is definitely going to slide the view to the top.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and just fix it by the code below. First I declare the `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` field in my class -

```
private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener tabSelectedListener;

 tabSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() { // I removed the boolean here because I don't know where to change the value of it.
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0){
                    nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, firstView.getTop());
                }else if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 1){
                    nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, secondView.getTop());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

finally, remove the `tabSelectedListener` before selection and add it again after selection.

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if (scrollY <= firstView.getBottom()){
                    /*First remove it*/
                    tabLayout.removeOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
                    /*Then add it again*/
                    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener)

                    clicked = false;
                } else if (scrollY >= secondView.getTop() && scrollY <= secondView.getBottom() ){
                     /*First remove it*/
                    tabLayout.removeOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
                     /*Then add it again*/
                    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener)
                    clicked = false;
                }

            }

        });
```